# How to pass Custom Authorization Header to my backend websocket service through WSO2 (API Manager)?

Tags: java, websocket, wso2

I am using a Websocket api in  WSO2. I need to pass custom header to my backend Websocket service.  I have found a documentation here 
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Adding+Mediation+Extensions

but it's for rest api call not for Websocket. So how can i send custom header  to my backend Websocket service through WSO2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send a custom header to the Web Socket backend in the initial WebSocket handshake. 
you can set it in the following format to the client handshake request.

```
websocket.custom.header.<required-header-name>
```

Ex: If the expected header is X-JWT-Assertion, the header that should be sent is

```
websocket.custom.header.X-JWT-Assertion
```

This feature support is added from API Manager v2.6.0

You could not use mediation sequences here since the rest of the communication is done with ws frames.

**Adding more information.**

Here is an example of a netty based web socket client which can be used to communicate with the WS API deployed in the API Manager. [1]

The authorization header is set in the Handshake as follows.

```
final WebSocketClientHandler handler = new WebSocketClientHandler(
                    WebSocketClientHandshakerFactory.newHandshaker(
                            uri, WebSocketVersion.V13, null, false, new DefaultHttpHeaders()
                    .add("Authorization", "Bearer e2238f3a-e43c-3f54-a05a-dd2e4bd4631f")));
```

This Authorization header is to authenticate with API Manager. If you need to send a custom header, you can add another header by modifying the above example as follows.

```
DefaultHttpHeaders headers = new DefaultHttpHeaders();
headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer e2238f3a-e43c-3f54-a05a-dd2e4bd4631f");
headers.add("websocket.custom.header.X-WS-UserName", "bob");

final WebSocketClientHandler handler = new WebSocketClientHandler(
                    WebSocketClientHandshakerFactory.newHandshaker(
                            uri, WebSocketVersion.V13, null, false, headers));
```

This header will be sent to the backend as,

```
X-WS-UserName : bob
```

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/download/attachments/57748790/sample-ws-client.zip?version=2&modificationDate=1484568275000&api=v2